# Appending char at beginning of string results in Memory Limit Exceeded

Tags: c++, stdstring

While doing a coding problem, let's say I have a `string s` of `length 50000`

I am creating an another string based on some constraints.

Below code is giving me result.

```
string res = "";

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    if(/* some constraint satisfied */)
    {
        res += s[i];
    }
}
```

Below code is throwing `Memory Limit Exceeded` on Online Judge.

```
string res = "";

for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(/* some constraint satisfied */)
    {
        res = s[i] + res;
    }
}
```

1. Is it creating a new string every time in second case?
2. If yes, then how can I avoid it while iterating backward.
3. Do I need to reserve the memory in the beginning itself?
4. If yes, what should be the size?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're problem is likely the order of `s[i] + res` vs. `res += s[i]`. The overloaded `operator+` is defined for operands of type `std::string` and `char`, respectively, but there's no overloaded operator for the other direction. The solution is to explicitly turn `s[i]` into a `std::string`: `res = std::string(s[i]) + res;`, or to use `std::string::append`: `res.append(0, 1, s[i]);`

Comment: Still getting the same error. Tried this: std::string: res = std::string(s[i]) + res;

Comment: Actually, disregard. I was way off. There is a defined operator+ for types of char and string. My mistake entirely.

Comment: See what `insert(0, 1, s[i])` does. I don't know how `std::string` allocates memory under the hood when doing various operations like this, but my guess is that `insert` will be smarter than the adding. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

Comment: If you have `string res = "";`, What is `s.length() - 1` in `for(int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)` then what is `s[i]` in that case?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, s[i] is the character at ith index in the string s.

Comment: @Bhawan `s.length() - 1` is `s.npos`, typically 2^32 - 1 or 2^64 - 1.

Comment: s.length() can not be 0. The given string length is 50000. s.length() is also giving me 50000.

Comment: `res` and `s` are two different strings.

Comment: Uugh -- coffee wore off a long time ago -- you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is very inefficient, because inserting a character at the beginning of a long string repeatedly means that all characters need to be shifted by one place.  Moreover, `res += s[i]` can make use of vacant capacity in the buffer of `res` (strings multiply their size when their capacity is exceeded so that repetitive insertion at the end does not require memory reallocation each time), whereas `res = s[i] + res` always allocates a new string and move the string into `res`.

Instead of rolling out your own loop and making a lot of mistakes (wrong index type, sub-optimal increment/decrement operator usage, wraparound bug), use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (defined in header [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)) along with [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) (defined in header [`<iterator>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator)):

```
std::string result;
std::copy_if(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
             [](char c) {
                 return /* constraint */;
             });
```

You can also use `reserve` if you know the rough number of characters that satisfy the criterion beforehand.